# Remove transfer encoding in Http Request

Tags: java, servlets, http-1.1, transfer-encoding

I am sending one SOAP request. It uses the encoding type as **`Trasfer-encoding chunked`**.

The request is not sent properly. I think some issue with content encoding.

```
Empty Request is sent. I am getting 500 error from server.

"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
"SOAPAction: "fir_auto_complete/fir_auto_completeListRequest"[\r][\n]"
"User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
"Host: localhost:9090[\r][\n]"
"Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
```

I have tried like this but does not seem to work. I am getting 500 error from server.

```
public Response getNumber(@Context final HttpServletRequest context, @QueryParam("name") final String name) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
    return Response.ok(JSONHelper.withJSONCallback(context, JSONHelper.toJSON(name))).header("charset", "utf-8").header("Content-Encoding", "gzip")build();
    }
```

The packets of data is sent is empty.

I think there is a issue with Transfer encoding type.

Can some one suggest how to change encoding type and what encoding type is suggested here.

Comment: so what is the server error?

Comment: @user2310289. Thanks for response. The error is HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]. Could you help me to fix this.

Comment: I would contact the people who wrote the server side code.

Comment: @user2310289.I contacted them. They said that issue with the Transfer Encoding chunked in header. If it can be changed to any other encoding for this request, it will be good.

Comment: You are sending a SOAP request *how?* You should also ask them why they don't support a transfer-encoding that has been in existence for about 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

try to set `setContentLength` to the size of the data being sent for no chunked transfer encoding